# Verifying the Jacobi identity for the semidirect product of Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, semidirect-product

> Given Lie algebras $S$ and $I$ and a Lie homomorphism $\theta \colon S\to \operatorname{Der} I$, we have the semidirect product to be the vector space $S\oplus I$ with operation
> $$
>   (s_{1},x_{1})(s_{2}x_{2})
>   :=
>   ([s_{1},s_{2}],[x_{1},x_{2}]+\theta(s_{1})x_{2}-\theta(s_{2})x_{1}).
> $$
> Show that this is a Lie algebra.

So I can easily verify the skew-symmetric but I can't seem to work out a nice way of proving the Jacobi identity. Am I missing a simple trick or must you perform the tedious calculation to show this? Thanks.

Comment: You can at least simplify the calculation and break it into parts by proving the Jacobi identity for a basis (or generating system) of $S\oplus I$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I could simplify the calculation in this way since $S$ and $I$ are arbitrary Lie algebras so we know nothing of their basis structure?

Comment: I only wanted to mean that you can check it only on special form entities like $(s_1,0)$ or $(0,x_1)$. It simplifies the calculation but introduces many cases. I guess though this is not the ultimate answer you're after.

Comment: Actually I do think this makes the calculation SLIGHTLY more bearable since the Lie bracket is bilinear so we can write $$[(s_{1},x_{1}),[(s_{2},x_{2}),(s_{3},x_{3})]]=[(s_{1},0),[(s_{2},x_{2}),(s_{3},x_{3})]]+[(0,x_{1}),[(s_{2},x_{2}),(s_{3},x_{3})]]$$ Thanks for your input, I will take all the help I can get!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation is no longer tedious if you split it up into four cases. Since the Jacobi identity is trilinear we only need to check it for one of the following cases:
$(s_1,0),(s_2,0),(s_3,0)$, or $(s_1,0),(s_2,0),(0,x_3)$, or $(s_1,0),(0,x_2),(0,x_3)$ or $(0,x_1),(0,x_2),(0,x_3)$. The cases themselves are immediate, because they follow from the facts that either $S$ is a Lie algebra, or that $I$ is a Lie algebra, or that the
$\theta(s_i)$ are derivations, or that $\theta$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism.

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why we can break this down into these 4 cases. In breaking it down to four cases, we never assume that $[-,-]$ is bilnear..

Comment: The Lie bracket is bilinear, so the "Jacobiator" is trilinear. So we *are* assuming it.

Comment: But the question is asking to verify that $[-,-]$ is indeed a well defined lie bracket operation, which means it is bilinear, antisymmetric and satisfies the Jacobi identity. Why don't we have to prove that this interesting candidate for a product of a lie algebra is bilinear?

I get that $[-,-]$ is bilinear on $S$ and $I$, but when we are trying to extend $[-,-]$ in a nonobvious way to $S \oplus I$ it seems to be that we would have to verify the bilinearity, which I am having a hard time doing

Comment: Infact, it seems like it's not bilinear...

Comment: It is certainly bilinear. The OP made a typo in the formula.