# Another identity implied by the Jacobi identity for semidirect product of Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, semidirect-product

I'm working through *Introduction to Lie Algebras* by Erdmann and Wildon.  In Chapter 3, Exercise 3.9 asks the reader to develop the semidirect product of Lie algebras.  I got very stuck on the verification of the Jacobi identity, but the link [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684193/verifying-the-jacobi-identity-for-the-semidirect-product-of-lie-algebras) suggested the hint/trick of breaking the identity down so there are zeros in each pair, which gets you the required verification.  However...

Recalling that the Lie bracket is defined as:
$$
[(s_1,x_1),(s_2,x_2)]=([s_1,s_2],[x_1,x_2]+\theta(s_1)(x_2)-\theta(s_2)(x_1)),
$$
where $\theta:S\rightarrow \text{Der}(X)$, I did the obvious thing and try to push the identity through as far as I could, simplifying along the way, and the most simplification I could achieve was to get:
$$
(0,\theta(s_1)[x_2,x_3]+\theta(s_2)[x_3,x_1]+\theta(s_3)[x_1,x_2]),
$$
which, if the Jacobi holds, must equal 0, which implies that in any semidirect product, this is true:
$$
\theta(s_1)[x_2,x_3]+\theta(s_2)[x_3,x_1]+\theta(s_3)[x_1,x_2]=0.
$$

I couldn't figure out how to prove this, but is this an actual known identity in semidirect products?  That seems like a very restrictive condition.

For reference, here are the steps of my calculation.  Start here:

$$
[(s_1,x_1),[(s_2,x_2),(s_3,x_3)]]+[(s_2,x_2),[(s_3,x_3),(s_1,x_1)]]+[(s_3,x_3),[(s_1,x_1),(s_2,x_2)]].
$$

Then we have:
$$
[(s_2,x_2),(s_3,x_3)]=([s_2,s_3],[x_2,x_3]+\theta(s_2)(x_3)-\theta(s_3)(x_2)),
$$

$$
[(s_3,x_3),(s_1,x_1)]=([s_3,s_1],[x_3,x_1]+\theta(s_3)(x_1)-\theta(s_1)(x_3)),
$$

$$
[(s_1,x_1),(s_2,x_2)]=([s_1,s_2],[x_1,x_2]+\theta(s_1)(x_2)-\theta(s_2)(x_1)).
$$

Then,

$$
[(s_1,x_1),([s_2,s_3],[x_2,x_3]+\theta(s_2)(x_3)-\theta(s_3)(x_2))]=
([s_1,[s_2,s_3]],[x_1,[x_2,x_3]]+\theta(s_1)([x_2,x_3]+\theta(s_2)(x_3)-\theta(s_3)(x_2))-\theta([s_2,s_3])(x_1)),
$$

$$
[(s_2,x_2),([s_3,s_1],[x_3,x_1]+\theta(s_3)(x_1)-\theta(s_1)(x_3))]=
([s_2,[s_3,s_1]],[x_2,[x_3,x_1]]+\theta(s_2)([x_3,x_1]+\theta(s_3)(x_1)-\theta(s_1)(x_3))-\theta([s_3,s_1])(x_2)),
$$

$$
[(s_3,x_3),([s_1,s_2],[x_1,x_2]+\theta(s_1)(x_2)-\theta(s_2)(x_1))]=
([s_3,[s_1,s_2]],[x_3,[x_1,x_2]]+\theta(s_3)([x_1,x_2]+\theta(s_1)(x_2)-\theta(s_2)(x_1))-\theta([s_1,s_2])(x_3)).
$$

Things start to go our way, where you recognize the Jacobi identity for the underlying Lie algebras.  Adding across components, we get that $[s_1,[s_2,s_3]]+[s_2,[s_3,s_1]]+[s_3,[s_1,s_2]]=0$ and $[x_1,[x_2,x_3]]+[x_2,[x_3,x_1]]+[x_3,[x_1,x_2]]=0$.  In the second component, here's what's "left:"

$$
\theta(s_1)([x_2,x_3]) + \theta(s_1)\circ\theta(s_2)(x_3) -\theta(s_1)\circ\theta(s_3)(x_2) - \theta([s_2,s_3])(x_1) +
\theta(s_2)([x_3,x_1]) + \theta(s_2)\circ\theta(s_3)(x_1) -
\theta(s_2)\circ\theta(s_1)(x_3) - \theta([s_3,s_1])(x_2) +
\theta(s_3)([x_1,x_2]) + \theta(s_3)\circ\theta(s_2)(x_2) - 
\theta(s_3)\circ\theta(s_2)(x_1) - \theta([s_1,s_2])(x_3).
$$

Rearranging:

$$
\theta(s_1)([x_2,x_3])+\theta(s_2)([x_3,x_1])+\theta(s_3)([x_1,x_2]) +
\theta(s_1)\circ\theta(s_2)(x_3) - \theta(s_2)\circ\theta(s_1)(x_3) +
\theta(s_2)\circ\theta(s_3)(x_1) - \theta(s_3)\circ\theta(s_2)(x_1) +
\theta(s_3)\circ\theta(s_1)(x_2) - \theta(s_1)\circ\theta(s_3)(x_2) -
\theta([s_2,s_3])(x_1) - \theta([s_3,s_1])(x_2) - \theta([s_1,s_2])(x_3).
$$

Things cancel, for example:

$$
\theta(s_1)\circ\theta(s_2)(x_3) - \theta(s_2)\circ\theta(s_1)(x_3) - \theta([s_1,s_2])(x_3) = \theta([s_1,s_2])(x_3)-\theta([s_1,s_2])(x_3)=0.
$$

Comment: Can you include your calculation? Did you already use that $D_i=\theta (s_i)$ is a Lie algebra derivation? So $D_i([x,y])=[D_i(x),y]+[x,D_i(y)]$

Comment: I have computed the above identity for the example of the semidirect product $\mathfrak{sl}(2)\ltimes_{\theta} \mathfrak{r}_2$, where $r_2$ is the $2$-dimensional nonabelian Lie algebra, and it is not always zero. So I don't think the calculations are correct.

Comment: I added my calculations.

Comment: Oh nevermind.  I see where I went wrong.

Comment: Since the Jacobi identity is trilinear, we may assume that the pairs $(s_i,x_j)$ are of a special form. Then the calculation becomes much easier.